# Openlayers 2.12 + Firefox 15 = OSM Layer not showing

Tags: openlayers-2, openstreetmap

I know it's due to the [new Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/master/notes/2.12.md#osm-and-bing-layers) in OL 2.12, but it is still not functional to me. I've followed instructions on [here on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11358353/map-tiles-do-not-show-all-pink-in-firefox-using-openlayers-and-own-osm-server).

### Firefox version

15.0.1

### Apache2 config

In `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default` I've set:

```
<Directory /home/fradeve/public_html/ark-oia/*>            
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin *
</Directory>
```

### OL OSM layer config

```
var osm_layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM('OSM Layer', null, {
    transitionEffect: 'resize',
    tileOptions: {crossOriginKeyword: null},
    resolutions: [...],
    serverResolutions: [...]
})
```

But OSM layer is fine on Safari, Chromium 20.0.1132.47, but not in Firefox. What am I missing?

Comment: Access Control Allow Origin doesnot restrict Image tiles. It may be firefox issue